# Does Parse's PFQuery findObjects() method re download the objects that have already been pinned?

Tags: parse-platform

I'm writing a method to update the localData for a certain table in Parse. However, I need to know if Parse recognizes when an Object is already downloaded (or pined). Meaning when I call findObjects() and it downloads all the PFObjects, does it re-download also the ones that are already saved?

Answer (score 1):

If you have enabled the localDataStore (`[Parse enableLocalDatastore]`) and pinned the objects, then yes, Parse will keep the local copy up to date. It does this whenever you call a remote query, if that object is held locally in a pin, it will update the local copy when it receives the data from Parse. It will also merge any local changes you have called `saveEventually` on with the remote changes.

The intent of the localDatastore is that you can then access the data when offline.

The typical pattern for this is to Query locally first `[query fromLocalDatastore]`, display those to the user, then call a remote query (i.e. without the `fromLocalDataStore`) afterwards to update the local objects and display latest to the user.